# Why this javascript and html code is not calculating the result?

Tags: javascript, html, math

This is the code:

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
function myFunction(var1,var2){
number=var1+var2
document.write(number)
}
</script>

<form>
Number 1 : <input type="text" name="no1"><br>
Number 2 : <input type="text" name="no2"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction(this.form.no1.value,this.form.no2.value)" value="submit">
</form>

<p id="demo></p

</body>
</html>
```

When I insert 10 for number 1 and 20 for number 2, the output is:

```
1020
```

But i want it to display 30.
What can i do?

**I have tried myFunction(10,20), the result is 30.

Comment: Look up the `parseInt` method.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: `number=+var1+ +var2;` also works, though it is hacky and less readable then `parseInt()` off course.

Comment: It will, but the OP seems to be just starting out, so less "magic" is better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simply use **parse the variable value to integer** using `parseInt()` method or add "+"before to your variable name. Because variables var1 and var2 returning **string**. To calculate those variable values, you need to convert it as a integer.

**using parseInt() method**

```
number=parseInt(var1)+parseInt(var2)
```

**use + before variable name to convert into integer,**

```
number= +var1 + +var2
```

try this code,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        function myFunction(var1,var2){
            number = parseInt(var1) + parseInt(var2)
            //another way number= +var1+ +var2
            document.write(number)
        }
        </script>
    <form>
        Number 1 : <input type="text" name="no1"><br>
        Number 2 : <input type="text" name="no2"><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="myFunction(this.form.no1.value,this.form.no2.value)" value="submit">
    </form>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

using parseInt() [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/girosova/1/)

using + before variable name [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jucirazi/1/)

Comment: +1 and just for the sake of mentioning it, a short-hand implicit cast would be: `number=+var1+ +var2;` *(space between + signs is important)* i.e: `"2" + "3"` is `"23"`, while `+"2"+ +"3"` is `5`. Though `parseInt()` is off course the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

modify your function with parseInt like:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(var1,var2){
        number=parseInt(var1)+parseInt(var2);
        document.write(number);
    }
</script>
```

You were getting output like `1020` because by default data from the textbox is taken as `text type`, so we need to convert it to `Number Type` first, for that we are using `parseInt`(for explicit conversion)

Answer (score 2):

Update your method to

```
function myFunction(var1,var2){
  number=parseInt(var1) + parseInt(var2)
  document.write(number)
}
```

As `this.form.no1.value` is returning a string, so both the numbers are concatenated as strings instead of summing up as numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript thinks you are appending strings... To make sure your javascript knows it's numbers your working with you need to convert it to that type.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        function myFunction(var1, var2){
            number = parseInt(var1, 10) + parseInt(var2, 10)
            document.write(number)
        }
        </script>
        <form>
            Number 1 : <input type="text" name="no1"><br>
            Number 2 : <input type="text" name="no2"><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="myFunction(this.form.no1.value,this.form.no2.value)" value="submit">
        </form>

        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

For more info about parseInt check this [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

Change your input tag to

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction(parseInt(this.form.no1.value, 10),parseInt(this.form.no2.value, 10))" value="submit">
```

OR

Change your JavaScript function to

```
    function myFunction(var1,var2){
      var number=parseInt(var1, 10)+parseInt(var2, 10);
      document.write(number);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the values you extract from your input fields are strings. When you add two strings, they are usually concatenated. Try looking at the javascript method `parseInt`as Evan suggests in the comments or look at `parseFloat`if you want to allow floats.

[parseFloat docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)

Your method would then look like this:

```
function myFunction(var1,var2){
    number = parseFloat(var1) + parseFloat(var2)
    document.write(number)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's now just string concatenation. Please use "parseInt()" to get the result.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your not doing a **calculation**, you are appending two Strings. In order to calculate the mathematical answer for *var1 + var2* you should parse them to Integers.

```
result = parseInt(var1) + parseInt(var2);
```

Comment: Ok, I will at least give +1s to other people, because more people came up with the same answer. Thanks.